# Calculating weekly change based on irregular weekdays (due to holidays)

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula

[image: Example]

How can I calculate weekly change based on irregular weekdays, such as weeks containing four working days?

I am thinking a 'countif' if there are only four days in a week, and then do `sum(day1:day4) on change%'s data`.

And if there are five days then `sum(day1:day5)`.

However, I am unable to write this in a code format.

Comment: Welcome. "weekly change"... I've been looking at your question and the image for 10 minutes and I don't understand what "weekly change" actually means. Please provide an explanation of just what you are trying to calculate. You might find it useful to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) .

Comment: weekly change referring to each friday i want to calculate the sum of 5 (or 4 if there's a holiday) working day's change%.

so if day 1 was 5%, day 2 was -2%, day 3 was 0%, day 4 was 1%, day 5 was 6%, i want to calculate the sum of each day's change, which is 10%. however some weeks only has 4 working days, so i cannot use a sum function repeatedly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

paste in **D2** cell and drag down:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(TEXT(A2, "ddd")="Fri", 
 TEXT(SUMPRODUCT(QUERY(QUERY(TO_TEXT({C$2:C, WEEKNUM(A$2:A), YEAR(A$2:A)}), 
 "where Col3 !=''"), 
 "select Col1 
  where Col2 = '"&WEEKNUM(A2)&"' 
    and Col3 = '"&YEAR(A2)&"'")), "0.00%"), ))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 1):

In the following answer, it is necessary to create two additional columns (which could be hidden if necessary) in the data range (`weeknum` and `weekday`) plus a `Weekly Lookup Helper Table`. The Helper table can be on a separate sheet; it can/should be 52 rows long (one for each working week).

The entire solution looks like this:
[image]

The formulas are:
**Working day data range**

- weeknum  (Cell B2)`=weeknum(A2,1)`
- weekday  (Cell C2)`=weekday(A2)`
- Value    (Cell D2) `User input`
- Daily Change (Cell E2) `=(C2-C3)/C3`
- Weekly Change (Cell F2) `=IF(ISERROR(vlookup(B2&" "&C2,$H$4:$K$7,4,false)), "", vlookup(B2&" "&C2,$H$4:$K$7,4,false))`

**Lookup Table**

- Lookup Key (Cell H4) `=I4&" "&J4`
- Week (Cell I4) - User Input; create a table 52 rows long, and enter week numbers 1 to 52 in this column
- maxifs (Cell J4) `=maxifs($C$2:$C,$B$2:$B,I4)`
- Weekly Change (Cell K4) `=sumif($B$2:$B,I4,$E$2:$E)`

---

**LOGIC**
**Helper table**
The helper table is important.
`maxifs`: this extracts the max weekday for each week number.
`Weekly Change`: sums the daily change by week number.
The lookup key is simply a concatenation of the values of "week" and "maxifs"; this will be a unique value.

**Working day range**
`"weeknum"` and `"weekday"` create relevant values for each day.
The `Friday weekly change` is a vlookup function searching on weeknum/weekday (as a string), and the search range is the helper table. The combination of weeknum and weekday will be a unique value, which enables the vlookup to be successful.

Comment: Oops. The colours in the answer are purely random (manual) to assist with visual identification of the days in a given week. The OP's colors are completely different, are CF, and identify the day of the week (such as Monday, Tuesday, etc).